# Generic parameters declaration in static member

Tags: java, generics

Why it is not allowed to define such a static member:

```
private static final <T extends Object> Map<Class<T>, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>> SPECIFIC_HANDLERS = new HashMap<>();
```

Instead it's only allowed to use it unspecified:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<?, ?, Boolean>> SPECIFIC_HANDLERS = new HashMap<>();
```

Is there a workaround so that I can define that both parameters to the BiFunction MUST be of the same type and that the key of the Map MUST be the class type of these parameters?

**Updated to clarify (because the suggestion of @Mena is not suitable for me):**

I want a map for the array equals method for a generic equals helper. The generic helper receives formally two Objects. If they are arrays I have to pass it to one of the overloaded Arrays.equals() method. I wandted to have a lookup for the correct method (Example 1):

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<?, ?, Boolean>> ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER = new HashMap<>();

static
{
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put( Object[].class,  (l, r) -> Arrays.equals( (Object[])  l, (Object[])  r ));
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put( boolean[].class, (l, r) -> Arrays.equals( (boolean[]) l, (boolean[]) r ));
    ....
}
```

and then using it like:

```
boolean equal = ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.get( anObj1.getClass()).apply(anObj1, anObj2);
```

The construct (according to Mena) does not even compile:

```
private static <T extends Object> Map<Class<T>, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>> getSpecificHandlers() 
{
    Map<Class<T>, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put( Object[].class,  (l, r) -> Arrays.equals( (Object[])  l, (Object[])  r ));
    result.put( boolean[].class, (l, r) -> Arrays.equals( (boolean[]) l, (boolean[]) r ));
    return result;
}
```

And if I populate the generated map outside the method:

```
 @SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<?, ?, Boolean>> ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER = (Map) getSpecificHandlers();

static
{
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put( Object[].class,  (l, r) -> Arrays.equals( (Object[])  l, (Object[])  r ));
    ...
}
```

then the whole type safety has gone because I have to do a (unchecked) typecast when assigning it to the final static member.

My Example 1 above works, but I have to cast the received lambda when using it :

```
private static <T extends Object> boolean equalsArray( T anArray, T anOtherArray) {
    Object o = ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.get( anArray.getClass());
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked")
    BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> func = (BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>) o;

    Boolean result = func.apply( anArray, anOtherArray);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If it's a static member, then there can only be one instance. Generics kind of don't make sense in this case... Alternatively, maybe make it a singleton?

Comment: If it's static and not final, there can be many assignments to that reference.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Actually, it is `static` _and_ `final`...

Comment: @tobias_k not talking about this particular case :) edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, it's a bit ugly, but works as requested.

First thing, note that `Map.get()` method takes raw `Object` type as argument, thus it is not possible for compiler to guess return type of this method based on the argument type. Instead of that return type comes from declaration of the field itself, and as it's declared using fixed type parameter (in your case it should be `Object`) - you get fixed return type for any invocation of `.get()`. Actually, same thing applies not only for `get()` method but for all you expect to act as type-parameterized methods.

Secondly, desired structure should add some restrictions on key and value pairs (you want value type to depend on the key type). This is usually done via type parameters. It doesn't work for field declaration but does work for type or method declaration.

So, with those two premnises, I end with the solution: introduce type that extends `Map` with additional type correlation and with additional generic `get()` method (you may add more generic methods, of course).

```
public static class HandlerMap<T> extends HashMap<Class<? extends T>, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <U extends T> BiFunction<U, U, Boolean> getStrict(Class<? extends U> key) {
        return (BiFunction<U, U, Boolean>) get(key);
    }
}

private static HandlerMap<Object> ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER = new HandlerMap<>();

static {
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put(Object[].class, (l, r) -> Arrays.equals((Object[]) l, (Object[]) r));
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put(boolean[].class, (l, r) -> Arrays.equals((boolean[]) l, (boolean[]) r));

    //WARNING - type safety breaks here
    ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.put(int[].class, (l, r) -> Arrays.equals((boolean[]) l, (boolean[]) r));

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BiFunction<int[], int[], Boolean> biFunction = ARRAY_EQUALS_HANDLER.getStrict(int[].class);
}
```

I used `HashMap` as superclass directly for shorter code. Note that `getStrict()` method is marked as unsafe (obviously, it is). And note also missing type coersion on `put()`.

I think now, that all that ugliness comes from that you actually want not `Map`, but something different. Yes, there is a common concept - structure with key-value pairs, but type coersion should work another way. `Map` used to restrict keys to certain type and values to another certain type, but you don't need it. What you need is something stronger - not only type coersion for keys and values separately, but also binding between key type and value type.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a generic method idiom (the type parameter declaration before the return type), for a constant declaration.

That idiom will not compile.

As mentioned elsewhere too, you cannot use a class generic type in a static context.

What you **can** do as a workaround is to declare a static method instead of a constant - something in the lines of:

```
private static final <T extends WhateverBound> Map<Class<T>, 
    BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>> 
    getSpecificHandlers(T t) {

    // return new HashMap<Class<T>, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>>();
    // much easier on the eye - thanks Andy Turner
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

Assuming:

```
static class WhateverBound{}
static class Foo extends WhateverBound {}
```

You can then invoke your method as:

```
Map<Class<Foo>, BiFunction<Foo, Foo, Boolean>> map = 
getSpecificHandlers(new Foo());
```

Note of course that the `final` keyword here has a very different meaning, and can probably be omitted altogether.

**Or...**

You can keep it as a constant and repeat the wildcard/boundary pattern across all type parametrization.

For instance:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends WhateverBound>, 
     BiFunction<? extends WhateverBound, ? extends WhateverBound, Boolean>> 
       SPECIFIC_HANDLERS = new HashMap<>();

static {
    SPECIFIC_HANDLERS.put(Foo.class, (f, ff) -> true);
}
```

Comment: @AndyTurner hah it **would**! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. But for my purpose it does not work. The construct

Comment: @Heri you're welcome. Not clear what doesn't work for you from your comment though...

Comment: Sorry, wanted to explain here why, but hit enter too fast. See my updated question above

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you have in mind is possible using just the member declaration. What you could do is to *hide* the map itself, and provide stricter methods for *accessing* the map.

For example, like this:

```
class FunctionMapper {

    private final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<?, ?, Boolean>> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void map(Class<T> c, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> f) {
        MAP.put(c, f);
    }

    public <T> BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> get(Class<T> c) {
        return (BiFunction<T, T, Boolean>) MAP.get(c);
    }

    public <T> Boolean apply(T o1, T o2) {
        return get((Class<T>) o1.getClass()).apply(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

In your equality helper, you can use it like this:

```
    FunctionMapper mapper = new FunctionMapper(); // make this static final
    mapper.map(String.class, (s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2) == 0);
    System.out.println(mapper.apply("foo", "bar"));
```