# Using a member variable of raw type, then converted to the appropriate type "on demand"

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

The question I am posing here is somewhat related to 
[Generic parameters declaration in static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774313/generic-parameters-declaration-in-static-member)

I found myself using raw types for declaring several member variables (each of its own distinct type) in a non-generic class,  I am wondering if there is an alternative solution.

If there were only one such variable, then one would make the class generic and there would be no need to use a raw type. Instead, given the possibly large number of such types, making the class generic would be cumbersome.

One could also avoid the raw type by using generic methods to provide such variables. However this would entail creating a new instance at each invocation.

Here is a piece of code that illustrates the problem:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class PreferencesForFruits {

interface Fruit{}
static class Banana implements Fruit {}
static class Apple implements Fruit {}

// a class describing the packaging of a fruit;
// it depends on the type of consumer of the fruit
static class FruitBox<F extends Fruit, C extends Consumer<F>> {
    // constructor (note that it doesn't accept wildcards, 
    // therefore its client must specify fixed types) 
    FruitBox(F f,C c) {}
}

// preferences for apples and bananas specified in two nested classes:
// 
public static class PrefsForApples<AC extends Consumer<Apple>> {
    // a functional object specifying 
    // how to pack a fruit for a customer
    BiFunction<Apple,AC,FruitBox<Apple,AC>> packingBiFunction = 
         (Apple a, AC ac) -> new FruitBox<Apple,AC>(a,ac);
}
//
public static class PrefsForBananas<BS extends Consumer<Banana>> {
    // ......
}

// convenience methods to obtained preferences;
// the argument is used here only to fix the generic type of the output
//
static <AC extends Consumer<Apple>> 
PrefsForApples<AC> newPrefsForApples(AC appleConsumer) {
    return new PrefsForApples<AC>();
}
//  
static <BC extends Consumer<Banana>> 
PrefsForBananas<BC> newPrefsForBananas(BC bananaSupplierDummy) {
    return new PrefsForBananas<BC>();
}

/*
 *  Now using fields of raw type to avoid creation of distinct instances  
 */

// Here are the raw type variables mentioned in the question:
private PrefsForApples prefsForApples;
private PrefsForBananas prefsForBananas;

// the convenience methods convert the raw type 
// to the required type 

<AC extends Consumer<Apple>> 
PrefsForApples<AC> prefsForApplesRaw(AC appleConsumer) {
    return (PrefsForApples<AC>) prefsForApples;
}

<BC extends Consumer<Banana>> 
PrefsForBananas<BC> prefsForBananasRaw(BC bananaSupplierDummy) {
    return (PrefsForBananas<BC>) prefsForBananas;
}
```

Comment: In most cases you can use `<?>` instead of raw type.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki which is like `root` for all generics, this will hardly solve anything

Comment: @Eugene I guess it will give a few more compiler checks, not much but better than raw type.

Comment: @Karol Actually it looks like the method `prefsForApplesRaw` works equally well after adding `<?>` to `prefsForApples` so that indeed there is probably no need to use raw types here. I was mistaken in thinking that the cast `(PrefsForApples<AC>)` would be applicable only to a raw type. But I still can't get rid of the above unchecked cast, it seems. So I guess my question should have been: Is there a way to avoid this unchecked cast? In what circumstances can this be unsafe?